# How to map iscsi device to /dev/sdX

Tags: iscsi

I have an initiator (Debian 7) connected to two targets. Each target provide multiple iscsi devices.

On the initiator, iscsi devices are mapped randomly to /dev/sdx, for example :

```
target1-iscsi1 -> /dev/sdb
target1-iscsi2 -> /dev/sdc
target2-iscsi1 -> /dev/sdd
target1-iscsi3 -> /dev/sde
target2-iscsi2 -> /dev/sdf
```

I would like to re-map isci devices to have a more "logical" mapping such as :

```
target1-iscsi1 -> /dev/sdb
target1-iscsi2 -> /dev/sdc
target1-iscsi3 -> /dev/sdd
target2-iscsi1 -> /dev/sde
target2-iscsi2 -> /dev/sdf
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What I would suggest is instead of using /dev/sdX use /dev/disk/by-id/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a physical host on hand, but have a look at `/etc/udev/rules.d`, this is the place where physical devices are linked to unix devices.

Comment: I went that way with no luck, I created a rule file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` naming the device with the ID obtained bay running `/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id --whitelisted --replace-whitespace --device=/dev/sdX`, then I restarted udev and open-iscsi but it doesn't seem to have any effect.